# How to remove sensor for rear tailgate

Tags: sensor, battery-drain

Would like to remove the dashboard light for the tailgate-open sensor in my van (Kia Pregio) because it stays on even with the key removed from the vehicle.

There's no fuse for it, so I put a piece of duct tape over the sensor but it keeps falling off. I'd like to hard wire the wires coming from the sensor so it does not draw on the battery anymore. Can I simply disconnect them? I'm not sure if open circuit = light on or closed circuit = light on. I guess closed but I thought I'd look to ask somebody before I did something permanent.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which way the switch would work with it being open or closed to denote the the hatch being closed. What I can tell you is to remove the switch so you have access to the wiring. Cut the two wires attached to the switch. Connect the two wires together and see if the light is on or off. If on, disconnect the two wires, tape them up and stuff them back into the hole (or wherever they came from). If off, tape them over so the two wires will not come apart and stuff them back to wherever they came from. Reattach the switch to where you pulled it from to cover up any hole which may be present.

Comment: I'd suggest pulling off just one wire and either leaving it loose or connecting it to the other. Then put everything back together. That way you're less likely to lose the wires. Or you could just replace the switch.

Comment: @dlu - I agree this would work as well. I don't think from the description the switch is really the issue here.